# How to push text to the edge in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui

I understand that this is elementary for the experienced. But please do not scold the newbie.
With arrows I showed what I want.
Here is my code

```swift
HStack {
    Text("Сумма займа")
        .padding()
    Text("\(Int(loanAmount)) руб")
        .bold()
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following:

```
HStack {
    Text("Сумма займа")
    Spacer()
    Text("\(Int(loanAmount)) руб")
        .bold()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use a flexible frame.

```
    Text("\(Int(loanAmount)) руб")
        .bold()
        .frame(maxWidth: .infinity, alignment: .trailing)
```

This expands the frame of Text to the maximum available space. It is an alternative to using Spacer in Stacks.